# Using deprecated subfigure package and succeeding subfig package in parallel

Tags: subfloats, subfig

I have a lot of figures in my document and unfortunately used the deprecated subfigure package. Now, I don't want to change all figures to the better subfig package, but instead, want to use it for new figures and in order to make the caption of a subfigure wider than the subfigure (using `\makebox`). But only one package works either subfigure or subfig. Is there a way to use both packages in parallel?

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,openrigth,oneside,bibliography=totoc,headspline]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mwe}


\begin{document}
%   \begin{figure}
%       \centering
%       \subfigure[Subigure 1]{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-a}
%       \label{fig10}}
%       \subfigure[Subfigure2]{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-a}
%       \label{fig11}}
%       \caption{Test figure 1 with subfigure command.}
%       \label{fig1}
%   \end{figure}
    \begin{figure}
        \subfloat[Subfloat 1]{\makebox[1.2\width][c]{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-a}\label{fig20}}}
        \subfloat[Subfloat 2]{\makebox[1.2\width][c]{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-a}\label{fig21}}}
        \caption{Test figure 2 with subfloat command.}
        \label{fig2}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The goal would be that the MWE also compiles when all text is uncommented.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to use both, imho. Decide for one. If you want to update to `subfig`,  you could just as well consider upgrading to `subcaption` and update all subfigures of your document. Or just stay with the old package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure where's the problem with changing `\subfigure` into `\subfloat`.

Anyway, you can use the old command:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,openright,oneside,bibliography=totoc,headsepline]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[config=altsf]{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mwe}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering

\subfigure[Subfigure 1\label{fig10}]{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-a}}
\subfigure[Subfigure 2\label{fig11}]{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-a}}

\caption{Test figure 1 with subfigure command.}\label{fig1}

\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering

\subfloat[Subfloat 1\label{fig20}]{\makebox[1.2\width]{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-a}}}
\subfloat[Subfloat 2\label{fig21}]{\makebox[1.2\width]{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-a}}}

\caption{Test figure 2 with subfloat command.}\label{fig2}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Note that I made several fixes.

[image]